# execute function using Ext.Loader.setConfig with ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Im trying to create a path with ExtJS using `Ext.Loader.setConfig`, im following the example from [Api Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setConfig) but every time i try to execute the method `holaMundo` not works and not show any error.

This is the code of `NombreClase.js` in js/pruebapath/miprueba/

```
Ext.define('js.pruebapath.miprueba.NombreClase', {
    constructor : function () {
        return this
    },
    holaMundo : function () {
        alert("¡¡Hola Mundo!!");
    }
});
```

This is the code of app.js

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled : true,
    paths : {
        'modelo' : "js/pruebapath/miprueba"
    }
});

Ext.require('modelo.NombreClase');

Ext.onReady(function () {
    var prueba = Ext.create('modelo.Nombreclase');
    prueba.holaMundo();
});
```

I tried to change the code of NombreClase.js to `Ext.define('modelo.NombreClase', {` shows an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found, was an upcase error:

**Wrong:**

```
var prueba = Ext.create('modelo.Nombreclase');
```

**Right:**

```
var prueba = Ext.create('modelo.NombreClase');
```